# How to Write ffmpeg code according to video data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

```
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                    : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                   : 337 MiB
Duration                    : 1 h 23 min
Overall bit rate mode       : Variable
Overall bit rate            : 562 kb/s
Encoded date                : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
Tagged date                 : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
gsst                        : 0
gstd                        : 5034271

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : Main@L3.1
Format settings             : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, Reference  : 3 frames
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 1 h 23 min
Bit rate                    : 431 kb/s
Width                       : 1 280 pixels
Height                      : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.019
Stream size                 : 258 MiB (77%)
Title                       : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 04/22/2020.
Writing library             : x264 core 155 r2901 7d0ff22
Encoded date                : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
Tagged date                 : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.709
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.709
Codec configuration box     : avcC

Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC LC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                    : mp4a-40-2
Duration                    : 1 h 23 min
Bit rate mode               : Variable
Bit rate                    : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel layout              : L R
Sampling rate               : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                  : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 76.8 MiB (23%)
Title                       : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 04/22/2020.
Encoded date                : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
Tagged date                 : UTC 2020-04-23 00:22:37
```

I have these information and I want to get same results with ffmpeg. What should I do? What codes do I have to use?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but using these commands will emulate most details.

## Command to emulate info shown in your question

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -level 3.1 -refs 3 -color_primaries bt709 -colorspace bt709 -color_trc bt709 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24000/1001,format=yuv420p" -b:v 431k -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart -brand mp42 output.mp4
```

## Command to emulate info shown in your comment to my answer

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -level 4 -refs 3 -color_primaries bt709 -colorspace bt709 -color_trc bt709 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p" -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes I'm doing a test about a video. I can not share picture I do not know why. I wish I had a chance to chat with you. so I can give the details about it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKzpE.png these are the details of the video.

Comment: @Tevfik 1) I'm not sure what I'm looking at. Are those the details you want to emulate, or or those the details of the input file you want to convert? 2) Please don't make screenshots of text. It's always better to copy and paste text. Then you can edit your question to include it or provide a link to a pastebin site. Images of text are harder to use than plain text. 3) Did my answer not provide a solution to your original question?

Comment: Not really @Ilogan. these infos are fromm a rendered video.

Comment: @Tevfik It is unclear what you actually want, so I had to make a guess. See updated answer.

Comment: @Tevfik Did the commands not provide the output attributes you wanted?

Comment: they are working but maybe I don't  know how to do :(

Comment: @Tevfik What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to help my friend who doesn't know English @Ilogan. Thanks for your help...